# Dynamic SQL declaration executed by batch file

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a proficient coder for SQL queries so I need some help with this one.

Here is my attempt:

```
DECLARE @ID AS varchar(max) = 'SELECT ID FROM Price WHERE ID = ''123456''';
DECLARE @VALUE as varchar(max) = 'SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM PriceData WHERE PriceID=''@ID' ORDER BY UpdatedOn DESC';

INSERT INTO PriceData VALUES (@ID,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),@VALUE,GETDATE())
```

So essicently I have two tables PRICE and PRICEDATA. PRICE has the PriceID I want from the ID '123456' so I decalre that as @ID and then the VALUE is the most recent value from PriceData by the ID '123456' so I order by the descending order and get the first element, then i insert into PriceData with the new values for today. Obviously this does not work I tried playing around with EXEC(@SQL) after i keep appending to the script but that also didn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: @ID has to be BIGINT and @VALUE has to be FLOAT but since i'm declaring SQL statement I had to make them varchar for the moment

PSS: Also im saving this sql script as an SQL file and running this command in a batch file

 sqlcmd -S "db" -i "C:\MYSQL.sql"

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag. As far as I can tell, this question is about Microsoft SQL Server, and it has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: I removed the `batch-file` tag.  That tag is intended for `.bat` scripting for the Windows console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a dynamic SQL or any variables here. Just an `Insert from select` should work

```
INSERT INTO PriceData
SELECT TOP 1 P.ID,
             Cast(Getdate() AS DATE),
             Value,
             Getdate()
FROM   PriceData PD
       JOIN Price P
         ON P.ID = PD.PriceID
WHERE  ID = '123456'
ORDER  BY PD.UpdatedOn DESC
```